# ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing LPX-00210: expected '<' instead of 'M' Error at line 1

Tags: xml, oracle

I had this query working properly for years until recently where i changed another query in the collector and saved.  I didnt change this xml query at all, but now its failing on the xml part.  Im and definitely not versed well in xml so im looking for some help to see where the issue is.  Here is the error message i am receiving:

> ORA-31011: XML parsing failed ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML
>   processing LPX-00210: expected '<' instead of 'M' Error at line 1
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 0 ORA-06512: at line 1

Here is my query that worked properly and now is not:

```
select Distinct trim(B.RoleID) as RoleID,
             replace(replace(extractvalue(value(C), '/item/menu') || ' >' ||
             extractvalue(value(C), '/item/submenu1') || ' >' ||
             extractvalue(value(C), '/item/submenu2') || ' >' ||
             extractvalue(value(C), '/item/label'), ' > > >', ' >'),' > >', ' >') as Res,
             extractvalue(value(C), '/item/name') as Action,
             extractvalue(value(C), '/item/visible') as visible
             from PLPROD_MORT.MENU A, 
             (SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('Processing and Closing (Group A)') AS RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('Branch Consumer (Group B)') AS RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('Branch Level Input (Group C)') AS RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('DU (Group D)') AS RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('Escrow Accounting (Group E)') AS RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('Override Locking - PE (Group F)') AS RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('Post Closing (Group G)') AS RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('Servicing - Reconciliation - Loan Support (Group H)') AS RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('Point of Sale Consumer (Group I)') AS RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('Training (Group J)') AS RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('Secondary Marketing (Group M)') AS RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('Originator (Group O)') AS RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('Appraisal (Group P)') AS RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('Quality Control (Group Q)') AS RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('Rate Lock (Group R)') AS RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('Servicing (Group S)') AS RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('Lock - PE (Group T)') AS RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('Underwriting (Group U)') AS RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('Test X Level (Group X)') AS RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('Management Override (Group Y)') AS RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('Test (Group Z)') AS RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('All screens and stages (No Groups)') As RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('Inquiry Only (Access I)') As RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('Operator (Access O)') As RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('Preferred Operator (Access P)') As RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union  
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('Supervisor (Access S)') As RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU
             union
             SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("MENUNAME") AS Menu, TRIM("MENUNAME") || ' - ' || upper('No Access') As RoleID FROM PLPROD_MORT.MENU) B,
             table
             (XMLSEQUENCE
             (extract
             (XMLTRANSFORM
             (XMLTYPE(A.MENUDATA),
              XMLTYPE('<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/><xsl:template match="/"><menus><xsl:for-each select="//menu"><item><name>Menu</name><menu><xsl:value-of select="@label"/></menu><submenu1/><submenu2/><label/><mnemonic><xsl:value-of select="@mnemonic"/></mnemonic><visible><xsl:value-of select="@visible"/></visible></item></xsl:for-each><xsl:for-each select="//menu/item"><item><name>Menu Item</name><menu><xsl:value-of select="../@label"/></menu><submenu1/><submenu2/><label><xsl:value-of select="@label"/></label><mnemonic><xsl:value-of select="@mnemonic"/></mnemonic><visible><xsl:value-of select="@visible"/></visible></item></xsl:for-each><xsl:for-each select="//menu/submenu"><item><name>Submenu</name><menu><xsl:value-of select="../@label"/></menu><submenu1><xsl:value-of select="@label"/></submenu1><submenu2/><label/><mnemonic><xsl:value-of select="@mnemonic"/></mnemonic><visible><xsl:value-of select="@visible"/></visible></item></xsl:for-each><xsl:for-each select="//menu/submenu/item"><item><name>Submenu Item</name><menu><xsl:value-of select="../../@label"/></menu><submenu1><xsl:value-of select="../@label"/></submenu1><submenu2/><label><xsl:value-of select="@label"/></label><mnemonic><xsl:value-of select="@mnemonic"/></mnemonic><visible><xsl:value-of select="@visible"/></visible></item></xsl:for-each><xsl:for-each select="//menu/submenu/submenu"><item><name>Submenu</name><menu><xsl:value-of select="../../@label"/></menu><submenu1><xsl:value-of select="../@label"/></submenu1><submenu2><xsl:value-of select="@label"/></submenu2><label/><mnemonic><xsl:value-of select="@mnemonic"/></mnemonic><visible><xsl:value-of select="@visible"/></visible></item></xsl:for-each><xsl:for-each select="//menu/submenu/submenu/item"><item><name>Submenu Item</name><menu><xsl:value-of select="../../../@label"/></menu><submenu1><xsl:value-of select="../../@label"/></submenu1><submenu2><xsl:value-of select="../@label"/></submenu2><label><xsl:value-of select="@label"/></label><mnemonic><xsl:value-of select="@mnemonic"/></mnemonic><visible><xsl:value-of select="@visible"/></visible></item></xsl:for-each></menus></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>'))
              , '//item'))) C
              where trim(A.MENUNAME) = B.MENU and extractvalue(value(C), '/item/visible') = 'true'
```

Comment: what is `A.MENUDATA`?

Comment: A.MENUDATA is the name of the column in the database that contains the xml i am trying to parse.

Comment: Does a Menuname contains a `<` or `>`? Try this to escape the characters: `UTL_I18N.ESCAPE_REFERENCE(TRIM("MENUNAME"), 'AL32UTF8')`

Comment: Tried adding, and didn't seem to work.  Not sure if i'm entering it in the correct spot or spots. I get invalid identifier for ESCAPE_REFERENCE

Comment: But what data is in that column? Sounds like you have a value that isn't actually XML, but we can't see your data. Try to `select XMLType(MENUDATA) from PLPROD_MORT.MENU` and I imagine you'll see the same error; then you'll need to track down which row has the bad value. And how it got, but that's a different issue...

Comment: i run that command, and throws 31 entries that say <error>.  It looks like the datatype is CLOB

Comment: So you'll need to find out why you have data in there that isn't valid XML. (We knew it was stored as CLOB or varchar2 because you're calling XMLType using it; which doesn't really matter here). You could possibly narrow it down based on your `B` values and the join you're doing. It may even be old data that you're now picking up for the first time for some reason. Or just inspect all the rows, or all 31 erroring rows. That's not really something we can help you with though.

Comment: Ok, well i appreciate the feedback.  Like i said XML coding is definitely not my expertise, so all this helps.  Thanks again.

Comment: It's not really about XML coding, it seems more like you have data that is not even remotely XML-like; I'd guess someone has put the literal string 'MENUDATA' in the column by accident - you get the same error if you do `select xmltype('MENUDATA') from dual`. But could be any string staring with M.

Answer (score 0):

You have data in your `PLPROD_MORT.MENU` table's `MENUDATA` column, which holds string values (CLOB in this case), that is not valid XML. From the error you're getting you have at least one value that starts with `M`, but you your testing in comments suggests you have 31 rows with non-XML values.

I'd speculate the value might be the literal string `'MENUDATA'` as that gets the same error:

```
select xmltype('MENUDATA') from dual;

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
select xmltype('MENUDATA') from dual
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00210: expected '<' instead of 'M'
Error at line 1
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 310
ORA-06512: at line 1
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.
```

but it's only really telling you it starts with an `M`. If it does have that literal value, though, I'd speculate further that someone has inserted or updated data and accidentally used a literal instead of an identifier, e.g. copying an existing entry using:

```
insert into PLPROD_MORT.MENU(MENUDATA) 
select 'MENUDATA' from PLPROD_MORT
where ...
```

instead of:

```
insert into PLPROD_MORT.MENU(MENUDATA) 
select "MENUDATA" from PLPROD_MORT
where ...
```

But that is several layers of speculation, and whatever caused that original data problem is nothing to do with the query you asked about - that is just seeing the symptoms of that bad data.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is complaining that "SYS.XMLTYPE" is not a valid xml column or type. It expects `<element>....</element>` format

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and I was able to solve that by correcting the Xpath within the `extractvalue()` function. I have entered a wrong Xpath for the CLOB value extraction. Hope this might be help full to solve your problem.